# Format number within ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to format number in ngModel but when I try like this  `<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="name.name.price | number:'1.2-3'">` it give me error. What should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular, [()] is two-way binding.

- []  is one-way attribute binding, which binds data from component to
  the view. The real-time date transform, which how pipe works, happens
  here.
- () is one-way event binding, which passes data from view to
  component. Pipe function doesn’t work here.

Therefore, you have to split [()] into [] and (), and only use pipe in [].
So, use :

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="name.name.price | number:'1.2-3'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try, change the `[(ngModel)]` syntax to this `[ngModel]`.

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="name.name.price | number:'1.2-3'">
```

**Note:** after this change ngModel value will change as string not number.